# Very slow plot with Matlpotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can anybody help how to optimize the **plot** function in python? I use **Matplotlib** to plot financial data.Here small function for plotting OHLC data. The time increase significantly if I add indicators or other data.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from pylab import *
import urllib2

def test_plot(OHLCV):

    bar_width = 1.3
    date_offset = 0.5
    fig = figure(figsize=(50, 20), facecolor='w')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    labels = ax.get_xmajorticklabels()
    setp(labels, rotation=0)

    month = MonthLocator()
    day   = DayLocator()
    timeFmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')

    colormap = OHLCV[:,1] < OHLCV[:,4]
    color = np.zeros(colormap.__len__(), dtype = np.dtype('|S5'))
    color[:] = 'red'
    color[np.where(colormap)] = 'green'
    dates = date2num( OHLCV[:,0])

    lines_hl = LineCollection( zip(zip(dates, OHLCV[:,2]), zip(dates, OHLCV[:,3])))
    lines_hl.set_color(color)
    lines_hl.set_linewidth(bar_width)
    lines_op = LineCollection( zip(zip((np.array(dates) - date_offset).tolist(), OHLCV[:,1]), zip((np.array(dates)).tolist(), parsed_table[:,1])))
    lines_op.set_color(color)
    lines_op.set_linewidth(bar_width)
    lines_cl = LineCollection( zip(zip((np.array(dates) + date_offset).tolist(), OHLCV[:,4]), zip((np.array(dates)).tolist(), parsed_table[:,4])))
    lines_cl.set_color(color)
    lines_cl.set_linewidth(bar_width)
    ax.add_collection(lines_hl,  autolim=True)
    ax.add_collection(lines_cl,  autolim=True)
    ax.add_collection(lines_op,  autolim=True)

    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(month)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(timeFmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(day)

    ax.autoscale_view()

    ax.xaxis.grid(True, 'major')
    ax.grid(True)

    ax.set_title('EOD test plot')
    ax.set_xlabel('Date')
    ax.set_ylabel('Price , $')
    fig.savefig('test.png', dpi = 50, bbox_inches='tight')
    close()

if __name__=='__main__':

    data_table = urllib2.urlopen(r"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&a=00&b=1&c=2012&d=00&e=15&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv").readlines()[1:][::-1]
    parsed_table = []
    #Format:  Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
    dtype = (lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').date(),float, float, float, float, int)

    for row in data_table:

        field = row.strip().split(',')[:-1]
        data_tmp = [i(j) for i,j in zip(dtype, field)]
        parsed_table.append(data_tmp)

    parsed_table = np.array(parsed_table)

    import time
    bf = time.time()
    count = 100
    for i in xrange(count):
        test_plot(parsed_table)
    print('Plot time: %s' %(time.time() - bf) / count)
```

The **result** is something like this. Average time execution on each plot is aproximately 2.6s. Charting in  **R** is much faster, but I didn't measure the performance and I don't want use **Rpy**, so I bielive that my code is inefficient.
[image]

Comment: You have a lot of `zip`s and splicing going in there with not much commenting as yo what it's achieving - as someone who used to do stuff like this all the time in the name of concise code, and advise against it. Coming back and looking over this later is going to suck...

Comment: I would advise trying [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) though. I'd answer the question with a demo, but I'm answering from my phone and it would be a nightmare...

Comment: My suggestion would be to reuse your figure, axes, linecollections and labels by creating a `FinanceChart` class. This way you could reuse the chart object 100 times, which saves you destroying it and recreating it each time. You can use `set_segments` on each of your linecollections to just change the data.

Answer (score 4):

This solution reuses a `Figure` instance and saves plots asynchronously. You could change this to have as many figures as there are processors, do that many plots asynchronously, and it should speed things up even more. As it is, this takes ~1s per plot, down from 2.6 on my machine.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import urllib2
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

class AsyncPlotter():
    def __init__(self, processes=mp.cpu_count()):
        self.manager = mp.Manager()
        self.nc = self.manager.Value('i', 0)
        self.pids = []
        self.processes = processes

    def async_plotter(self, nc, fig, filename, processes):
        while nc.value >= processes:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        nc.value += 1
        print "Plotting " + filename
        fig.savefig(filename)
        plt.close(fig)
        nc.value -= 1

    def save(self, fig, filename):
        p = mp.Process(target=self.async_plotter,
                       args=(self.nc, fig, filename, self.processes))
        p.start()
        self.pids.append(p)

    def join(self):
        for p in self.pids:
            p.join()

class FinanceChart():
    def __init__(self, async_plotter):
        self.async_plotter = async_plotter
        self.bar_width = 1.3
        self.date_offset = 0.5
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 20), facecolor='w')
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.labels = self.ax.get_xmajorticklabels()
        setp(self.labels, rotation=0)
        line_hl = LineCollection(([[(734881,1), (734882,5), (734883,9), (734889,5)]]))
        line_op = LineCollection(([[(734881,1), (734882,5), (734883,9), (734889,5)]]))
        line_cl = LineCollection(([[(734881,1), (734882,5), (734883,9), (734889,5)]]))

        self.lines_hl = self.ax.add_collection(line_hl,  autolim=True)
        self.lines_op = self.ax.add_collection(line_cl,  autolim=True)
        self.lines_cl = self.ax.add_collection(line_op,  autolim=True)

        self.ax.set_title('EOD test plot')
        self.ax.set_xlabel('Date')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Price , $')

        month = MonthLocator()
        day   = DayLocator()
        timeFmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(month)
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(timeFmt)
        self.ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(day)

    def test_plot(self, OHLCV, i):
        colormap = OHLCV[:,1] < OHLCV[:,4]
        color = np.zeros(colormap.__len__(), dtype = np.dtype('|S5'))
        color[:] = 'red'
        color[np.where(colormap)] = 'green'
        dates = date2num( OHLCV[:,0])
        date_array = np.array(dates)
        xmin = min(dates)
        xmax = max(dates)
        ymin = min(OHLCV[:,1])
        ymax = max(OHLCV[:,1])

        self.lines_hl.set_segments( zip(zip(dates, OHLCV[:,2]), zip(dates, OHLCV[:,3])))
        self.lines_hl.set_color(color)
        self.lines_hl.set_linewidth(self.bar_width)
        self.lines_op.set_segments( zip(zip((date_array - self.date_offset).tolist(), OHLCV[:,1]), zip(date_array.tolist(), OHLCV[:,1])))
        self.lines_op.set_color(color)
        self.lines_op.set_linewidth(self.bar_width)
        self.lines_cl.set_segments( zip(zip((date_array + self.date_offset).tolist(), OHLCV[:,4]), zip(date_array.tolist(), OHLCV[:,4])))
        self.lines_cl.set_color(color)
        self.lines_cl.set_linewidth(self.bar_width)

        self.ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)
        self.ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)

        self.ax.xaxis.grid(True, 'major')
        self.ax.grid(True)
        self.async_plotter.save(self.fig, '%04i.png'%i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print "Starting"
    data_table = urllib2.urlopen(r"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&a=00&b=1&c=2012&d=00&e=15&f=2013&g=d&ignore=.csv").readlines()[1:][::-1]
    parsed_table = []
    #Format:  Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
    dtype = (lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').date(),float, float, float, float, int)

    for row in data_table:
        field = row.strip().split(',')[:-1]
        data_tmp = [i(j) for i,j in zip(dtype, field)]
        parsed_table.append(data_tmp)

    parsed_table = np.array(parsed_table)
    import time
    bf = time.time()
    count = 10

    a = AsyncPlotter()
    _chart = FinanceChart(a)

    print "Done with startup tasks"
    for i in xrange(count):
        _chart.test_plot(parsed_table, i)

a.join()
print('Plot time: %.2f' %(float(time.time() - bf) / float(count)))
```